# anglularJs custom directive not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a custom directive in the below manor:

my main html file:

```
<body ng-app="boom">

<!--<section ng-include="'data-table.html'"></section>-->
<data-table></data-table>
</body>
```

my app.js file:

```
(function () {
     var app = angular.module('boom', ['ajs-directives']);
})();
```

my ajs-directive.js file:

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module('ajs-directives', []);

app.directive('dataTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'data-table.html',
        controller: function () {
            this.dataSet = dataSet;
        },
        controllerAs: 'tableData'
    };
});

var dataSet = [
    {
        prop1: 'one',
        prop2: 'two',
        prop3: 'three'
    },
    {
        prop1: 'four',
        prop2: 'five',
        prop3: 'six'
    }
];
})();
```

And my data-table.html file:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">

<table class="table table-fixed">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Entity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div id="media_table_height" class="table-content scroll-outer">
    <div class="scroll-inner">
        <table class="table-fixed">
            <tbody ng-repeat="data in tableData.dataSet">
                <tr class="data-row">
                    <td>{{data.prop1}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="data-row">
                    <td>{{data.prop2}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="data-row">
                    <td>{{data.prop3}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The issue I have is that nothing renders in my main html file.  Just the `<data-table></data-table>` tags are visible. I get no console errors in Google Chrome.

You might be able to see from my main html file that I have tried adding in the data-table.html file using the `ng-include="'data-table.html'"` attribute (and obviously creating a controller in the ajs-directive.js file).  When I did it this way it worked fine.

Just wondering why it won't work when I am using the directive - have been googling and tweaking for a few days but can't figure it out.

Comment: There is one obvious difference between `ajs-directives` (injected dependency) and `ajs-directive` (name of your module)

Comment: How are you hosting/running this code? I won't go as far as calling this an answer, but I seem to remember running into the same problem, and the cause for it not working, was that I tried to run the html file directly in a browser, and that angular needs a host/server til be able to actually load and render custom directives.

Comment: @devnull69 , sorry the directives thing was a typo on my behalf - have some sensitive data so was trying to rename everything.

Comment: @KjetilNordin I am hosting it using IIS Express v8.5.  In the Default Website node.

Comment: Then I'm useless. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

In it we can read:

> Angular **normalizes** an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase **normalized** name (e.g.
>   `ngModel`). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. `ng-model`).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> - Strip x- and data- from the front of the **element**/attributes.
> - Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

It seems to be a directive name problem.

NOTE: Dont use `data-` as a directive name or in your case **(i'm not sure)** all your elements called `<table>` will apply the `dataTable` directive. You can check it to see if i'm wrong :P

Comment: renamed everything to fooBar / foo-bar and it worked.  Thank you so much.  This has been killing me for ages :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (haven't figured it out yet) - angular doesn't recognize the element's name...

Quick solution - just change the name of your element and the binding in the directive E.G.

View:

```
<datatable></datatable>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('datatable', function () {...
```